# Modifying value of map pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std-pair

Can somebody explain why whenever I try to increment the pair nothing happens? I tried debugging it and although it goes to the incrementing line nothing happens.

EDIT: Here's the whole function

```
void VoteCollector::resultsBasedOnAge(std::vector<Voter>& voters)
{
    std::map<int,std::pair<int,int>> ageVoters;
    std::map<int,std::pair<int,int>>::iterator hasAge = ageVoters.begin();


    for(unsigned i = 0; i < voters.size(); i++)
    {
        if(ageVoters.find( voters.at(i).getAge() ) != ageVoters.end() )
        {
            if(voters.at(i).getVote() == "leave")
            {
                hasAge->second.first++;
            }
            else if(voters.at(i).getVote() == "stay")
            {
                hasAge->second.second++;
            }
            hasAge++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(voters.at(i).getVote() == "leave")
            {
                ageVoters.insert(std::make_pair(voters.at(i).getAge(),std::make_pair(1,0)));
            }
            else if(voters.at(i).getVote() == "stay")
            {
                ageVoters.insert(std::make_pair(voters.at(i).getAge(),std::make_pair(0,1)));
            }
            hasAge++;
        }
    }

    for(std::map<int,std::pair<int,int>>::iterator it = ageVoters.begin(); it != ageVoters.end(); it++)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " years -- " << it->second.first << " leave.\t" << it->second.second << " stay\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: Since you are not showing what `hasAge` is I doubt anyone can help much. I guess `hasAge` is actually a copy of what you wish to modify.

Comment: @NathanOliver do you have auto tag for MCVE, if yes how can I import it?

Comment: @Slava if you use `[mcve]` in the comment(do not use the code markup) it will auto expand to [mcve].  I also use [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to make better longer comments

Comment: Yes I am asking how to import this comment into AutoReviewComment, I installed it but by default it has only useless comments like "me too"

Comment: @Slava I am.  I just am at a different pc so I used the `[mcve]` shortcut.

Comment: @Slava Oh.  Click on auto then import/export at the bottom in the middle.  There you can type in your own.  You actually have to type it in it wont auto import. You can also use [these](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments)

Comment: @nwp added the whole function

Comment: Are you using C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, your code does not work because your `hasAge` is pointing to, I don't know, somewhere you probably don't mean to. You want to assign to it the result of `std::map::find`.

Assuming you are using C++11, the code can also be simplified:

```
void VoteCollector::resultsBasedOnAge(const std::vector<Voter>& voters)
{
    std::map<int, std::pair<int, int>> ageVoters;

    for (const auto& v: voters)
    {
        int age = v.getAge();
        const auto& vote = v.getVote();

        auto it = ageVoters.find(age);
        if (it != ageVoters.cend())
        {
            if (vote == "leave")
            {
                ++it->second.first;
            }
            else if (vote == "stay")
            {
                ++it->second.second;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (vote == "leave")
            {
                ageVoters.insert(std::make_pair(age, std::make_pair(1, 0)));
            }
            else if (vote == "stay")
            {
                ageVoters.insert(std::make_pair(age, std::make_pair(0, 1)));
            }
        }
    }

    for (const auto& v: voters)
    {
        std::cout << v.first << " years -- "
                  << v.second.first << " leave.\t"
                  << v.second.second << " stay\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Seems like the coffee wasnt enough :/ Thank you very much!!

Comment: you do not need condition to check if element is there already, but you should use `std::map::operator[]` instead: `auto &pair = ageVoters[age]; if( vote == "leave" ) ++pair.first; ...`

Comment: @Slava Careful, that has completely different semantics from `insert`. Using the brackets operator when there isn't an existing element will **first default construct an element, then assign the operand to that default-constructed element**. That'll almost surely have some performance impact for user defined types.

Comment: @Slava Hmm, I see you let that happen intentionally. Then if the OP wants to use it he can.

Comment: @ZizhengTai readability is more important than microoptimization, and this way you remove code duplication and I doubt that you can measure speed difference if any.

Comment: @Slava Readability is definitely important, but if `Voter` is some non-trivial class I doubt this is "micro-optimization". Anyway, since we don't know much about the type, let's let the OP decide.

Comment: What do you mean we do not know? It is `std::pair<int,int>`.

Comment: @Slava Oops, somehow I kept thinking it was `Voter`. Didn't think straight. You are right.

Comment: @SimeonGodinyachki Does my answer solves the problem? If yes, you can accept it.